# Image orientation when retrieving original image with readAsDataURL

Tags: javascript, image, html, orientation, filereader

I can't find any example for using FileReader.readAsDataURL and show the result image in a container with the **right image orientation**.

All the portrait images coming from my camera and iPhone devices have this issue. Only the portrait photos saved with adobe photoshop seem to not have this issue.

Here is one of the example system that I've found in the internet. My code is very similar:
http://www.onlywebpro.com/demo/file_reader/reader01.html

Notice when uploading this photo that it's loaded in landscape mode: http://www.rafaelsanches.com/IMG_3786.JPG

Notice that the image actually displays in landscape when using the browser to download it. When you save it to the disk and open with the finder it is previewed in portrait. (Probably the finder is clever to use the exif info)

Using exif.js I have discovered that the example image has an Orientation=8. The photos that are saved using photoshop have an Orientation=1.

Now, how do you guys suggest that I go about this? Should I plot it in a canvas and rotate depending on the exif information? Someone has a good tutorial about this? Have anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: For the moment I had to create a rotation tool in the web page. The user has to rotate manually. I believe it's possible to read the exif rotation and then rotate automatically, but processing a 10mb jpg with exif.js is very slow, so I'm not considering for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this problem today and resolved it...

After the line from the example where the image is created...

This is what I've done

```
var image = $(".uploaded");
                var img = new Image();

                img.src = e.target.result;

                if (img.complete) { // was cached
                    if (img.height < img.width) {
                        $(image).addClass("landscape").removeClass("portrait");

                    }
                    else {
                        $(image).addClass("portrait").removeClass("landscape");
                    }


                }
                else { // wait for decoding
                    img.onload = function () {
                        if (img.height < img.width) {
                            $(image).addClass("landscape").removeClass("portrait");

                        }
                        else {
                            $(image).addClass("portrait").removeClass("landscape");
                        }
                    }
                }
```